# JS npm package, Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I wanted to use this npm package https://github.com/nefe/number-precision, follow the steps but not working.

1. npm install number-precision --save--dep
2. `import NP from 'number-precision'` or`require()` on my JS file first-line , the error message will like this : 
   **Cannot define require && export** or
   **Cannot use import statement outside a module.**
3. `<script src="node_modules/number-precision/build/index.iife.js">import NP from 'number-precision </script>`

   It won't show any error message but in my js file, NP method still doesn't work.
4. `<script src="/workout.js"></script>` and put on my js file first-line`import NP from 'number- 
   precision'`

   I got this:

   **refused to execute script from 'http://0.0.0.0:2000/node_modules/number- 
   precision/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type 
   checking is enabled.**

   How do I correctly execute this npm package in my js file?

Answer (score 2):

To use imports in the browser, the file that does the imports needs to

a) be included with `type="module"`:

```
<script src="./workout.js" type="module"></script>
```

b) it only works for `script`s that are remote (that is, have a `src` attribute), it does not work for inline scripts.

Also note that you cannot shorthand reference files from `node_modules` in the browser, that only works when run with Node.

So, inside your workout.js, start like this:

```
import 'https://github.com/nefe/number-precision/blob/master/build/index.iife.js';
```

Unfortunately, that library author does not seem to supply a true ES6 module version ([I've just opened an issue on that](https://github.com/nefe/number-precision/issues/26)), so you cannot proceed like the page suggests and import the script into a variable `NP`.

Executing the script like the import shown above should work for you, though, and expose the library in the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation,  but I got another stupid question was how to deal with CORS if I using solution B?

Comment: Download the file, put it into your local htdocs or www folder and reference it from there.

Comment: Thanks! I got it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the standalone `<script>` tag, look at the content of the `iife.js`:

https://github.com/nefe/number-precision/blob/master/build/index.iife.js

```
var NP = (function (exports) {
'use strict';

// ...

return exports;

}({}));
```

It creates a global `NP` variable, so no importing is necessary, just put this first:

```
<script src="./index.iife.js"></script>
```

(change the `src` if needed, to the right path to your `index.iife.js`, however you want to structure it)

If you want to use this with Webpack, it works fine for me. After installing the package, `import` it in your entry point:

```
// src/index.js
import NP from 'number-precision'
console.log(NP.round(5, 5));
```

and then run Webpack to bundle the code:

```
npx webpack
```

and a working bundle will be produced in `dist/main.js` (or somewhere similar). Then link that bundle on your site.

Comment: Thanks, <script src="./index.iife.js"></script> no error message but it doesn't work, still can't use NP Method.

Comment: I did try it, it works fine for me. Make sure that the `index.iife.js` file is in the same directory as the HTML file.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this again.